# What does "within 15 minutes of either the opening or closing of classes" mean?

Tags: american-english

I came across this sentence:

> It is illegal to pass another vehicle in a school area, **within 15 minutes of either the opening or closing of classes** or at any time when children are on the school grounds or near the road.

Does it mean 15 minutes after the opening and the closing of class or 15 minutes before the opening and the closing of class or something else?

Comment: There's a half-hour time-window twice a day.  The 15-minute mark of each window corresponds with the opening time of the school in the morning and the closing time of the school in the afternoon.  These windows "straddle" the opening time and the closing time.

Comment: This is a badly worded warning.  Note that, in addition to the half-hour time-windows, there's also the entire time "when children are on the school grounds", which we can assume will be the whole period between the beginning and the end of classes.  A simpler version might be: *It is illegal to pass another vehicle in a school area from fifteen minutes before classes begin until fifteen minutes after classes end, or whenever children are present*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opening of classes: 8 am
The closing of classes: 3 pm

**within fifteen minutes of 8 am** means between 7:45 am and 8 am AND between 8 am and 8:15 am. Because both are "within" 15 minutes of the 8 am time.

The same structure goes for 3 pm.